# MediaRecorder: start failed

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I have googled about it but didn't find any solution

I am recording incoming and outgoing calls

code **works fine with outgoing call** but gives **exception on incoming call**

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/OK");
    dir.mkdirs();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/OK/"+"yes"+".3gpp");
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
       recorder.prepare();
       recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
         Log.d("illegal",e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.d("io",e.toString());
   }
```

**Logcat**

```
02-23 01:43:08.346  11231-11231/com.example.myapps.acr **I/record﹕ start**
02-23 01:43:08.426  11231-11231/com.example.myapps.acr **E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -38**
02-23 01:43:08.426  11231-11231/com.example.myapps.acr **D/illegal﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException**
```

Please help why its not working on incoming calls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recorder.prepare();
Thread.sleep(1000);
recorder.start();
```

For incoming  call it was taking time to prepare.

Hold the prepare for 1 sec and everything is worked fine.

Comment: you are testing on which version ?? It won't work in lolipop and above

Comment: Yes, Lollipop.
How can I make it work on Lollipop+ devices?

Comment: With Lollipop Android actively use voice cancellation to prevent audio from speaker going in to MIC. You need to enable loud speaker