# MediaRecorder start is been failing

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to record the call when phone call is accepted in android.

For that I have created a `Receiver`, in that I have kept code for `MediaRecorder` initial setup like this..

```
onReceive(){

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                      getAbsolutePath() + "/myrecording"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".3gp";

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
    recorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

 }
```

and in the phoneState change listener, for the case `OFF_HOOK`

```
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {
    Log.v(TAG,"call state is OffHook");
    try{
        recorder.prepare();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        recorder.start();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error occured here");
    }
    break;
}
```

every time when the control comes into this state I am getting error saying that

```
E/MediaRecorder(23056): start failed: -2147483648
W/System.err(23056): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960117/mediarecorder-start-failed) but it is also not working, could you please help me in this.Thanks